# Has Baen Books released a non-ARC version of Mission of Honor?

Tags: honorverse, baen

Baen books has a history of releasing compilation CDs of novels, licensed for free sharing (including electronically) in the bindings of 1st edition hardcovers.

Typically, this includes the series to that point (including the current book), other works by the author, and occasionally similar books.

The most recent in the Honor Harrington series, however (*Mission of Honor*), included an ARC (Advanced Reader Copy) of *Mission*, instead of the final release.  ARCs haven't completed their final editing run yet, they're essentially complete but DO contain errors.  I know from an online resource that this one in particular contains a rather glaring continuity error (a character essentially being in 2 places at once) due to Weber simply typing in the wrong name during a scene.

My preference would be to read the final version, not the ARC.  Is there a (legal) copy of Mission's final edit available online?

Comment: Given Baen's tendency to include **more** of content for free with time, IMHO this question is too localized time-wise.

Comment: @DVK - I don't believe it is, as the Harrington series has strayed from it's previous naming conventions (using 'Honor' or 'Flag' in each title) and a good answer would include a link to the non-ARC copy (most likely in another CD).  The Mission cd will continue to contain the ARC copy eternally, this question's answers may be invalidated (if it's 'no, not yet') but a correct answer would be valid just as eternally.

Comment: @Jeff - the first one ("Is there currently a (legal) copy") would only be non-localized if the answer is "yes" right now; since an answer of "no" would not necessarily hold true in the future. The second one is definitly sounding like "too localized" based on meta discussion of the topic (when will there be one). Anyway, it's just my opinion, I could be wrong :)

Comment: @DVK: I see your point, I've made some edits to correct that.

Comment: Relevant Meta thread: [How do we deal with questions about rumors and release dates?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/233/how-do-we-deal-with-questions-about-rumors-and-release-dates)

Comment: @Gilles: I don't really think that's the most relevant meta thread, I think that http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/502/whats-the-procedure-when-a-question-is-not-answerable-yet may be more accurate, assuming the current answer is "no, not yet"

Comment: @Jeff - looks good now, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can buy the non-ARC version of Mission of Honor from Baen now [for $6](http://www.webscription.net/p-1191-mission-of-honor.aspx). So it's definitely legally available. Just not for free. Yet.

Comment: Since it seems that there will be no further activity on this in the immediate future, I'm going to accept this answer.  I hope that, should the situation change, such information will be added.